# Refrigerator door not closing all the way

Tags: doors, refrigerator

We have a ~3 year old G.E. side by side refrigerator. The last few days we noticed that the door doesn't shut all the way by itself as it used to and have to give it a little nudge to fully shut it. I've tried several things that I found online. I checked and cleaned the seals around door, made sure nothing was blocking the door and took out all the heavier items from the door shelves but to no avail. I popped the rubber piece off of the top hinge thinking that there may be a tension adjustment there but didn't find any. I'm not thinking it's a leveling issue as the refrigerator has been in the same place all along. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Which model? Link to the instructions? Despite the fact that the fridge hasn't moved, I'd check level anyway, it's possible the floor has sagged _just_ enough to cause issues. Of course, if that's the case, then you can thank your fridge for being a canary for the sinking house.

Comment: Did you check the hinges for debris and rust?  Clean them and drop some oil on the moving parts.

Comment: Model GSS23GSKJCSS

https://www.searspartsdirect.com/manual/1dxcoanety-000432/ge-gss23gskjcss-side-by-side-refrigerator-parts

Comment: @Jack: What oil would you recommend? I recently oiled some hinges on a bedroom door with some (very) old 3-In-1 oil and there was an odor for a couple of days which I would find distasteful in a refrigerator.

Comment: Any general oil will do. Very old oil will smell a lot worse than new stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Enter the following search in your favorite search engine:
`GE side by side refrigerator door closing cam`

At the bottom of the problematic door, the plastic closing cam has probably worn away.  It looks like a small incline on a couple of its sides and the matching piece on the door will fall into the cam which moves the door towards the refrigerator cabinet.

Comment: Will check when I get a  chance. Thx.

Comment: I adjust my refrigerators so there is a little bit higher in the front then the back, that helps keep doors closed. It worked great years ago with kids.